# vdm Odata version compatibility

Tags: s4sdk

A conceptual question for vdm usage. Assume my OData evolves in a S4 cloud system and I am consuming it in a microservice. Since vdm needs the edmx file to generate entitiy classes, assume my odata has a new field or has eliminated one field that I do not use. If I do not change my edmx and will not generate new classes, will it be still work my call? And second question is, if one of the fields I use change, and I need to ensure 0 downtime, how do I handle 2 versions of generated classes in the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated OData VDM ultimately performs an OData call based on the fields that are used. So if you would not use fields that are removed, this should not be a problem. Note however, that such removals would have to be done in a new version of the SAP S/4HANA service.

Since breaking changes affect all consumers independent of whether the Java or JavaScript VDM of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK is used, developers of services in SAP S/4HANA have to follow a certain API guideline that includes specific deprecation rules.

So, if a breaking change is really required, according to the S/4HANA API guideline, a new version of the service has to be published and this will be also available with a different URL. This then gives you the possibility to migrate from an old to a new version without interruptions.